# Kivy standalone android apk on windows

Tags: android, python, kivy

I've been learning Kivy and how to create Android apps. My question is, is there a way to compile a kivy made app as a standalone apk on windows? Something similiar to buildozer for linux? I'm wanting to create an app that I will be releasing on the Google and Amazon app stores. I've been using Kivy Launcher to test run the apps, but obviously making everyone first install the launcher before your app is not ideal. I would just be using buildozer, but I keep running into install issues with it and a few other required files. I read somewhere before that I would need to use Python-for-Android (Py4A), but I can't seem to find where I read that. I've been reading through they kivy docs and searching forums, but I can't seem to find the answer i'm looking for. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: There are these Apache Cordova tools and node.JS where you could possibly execute a .py script using the node.JS, (e.g. with an Azure web server, install the base, pre-compiled Python + Kivy modules by streaming them all in). Will see soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kivy's tools do *not* support windows right now. You can see the [documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html) for options and instructions.

One thing not listed there is that tito has been developing a cloud builder to compile apks, whose frontend will work on windows, but I don't know his timescale for releasing it.

Comment: @inclement is your answer still up-to-date about Windows support? [See Kivy page](http://kivy.org/#download)

Comment: @codeReview: Nothing has changed here - Kivy itself supports windows fine (and always did) but compiling an APK is not possible there. However, I've been working in a [revamped python-for-android](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/tree/revamp) that *does* target windows support, not by compiling everything but by doing a binary download of prebuilt android components. This will hopefully be ready soonish.

Comment: Thanks for the notice. I was about to begin installation on Windows to target Android 4.4 x86. So it seems that would be a big mistake. xubuntu 14.04.2 (amd64) with CPython 3.3 x86 is what seems to be the safe way to accomplish my Python/Kivy-to-Android app.

Comment: python-for-android also doesn't currently support python3 - this is another (not yet complete) feature in my revamped python-for-android, so hopefully it will be available soon.

Comment: Correction the requirements are currently [this](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html#packaging-your-application-into-apk), since Bulldozer is in alpha. Requirements are more limiting than I hoped for. I am seeing contradicting requirements which is more confusing (see [1](http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html#ubuntu-12-04-with-python-3-3) [2](http://python-for-android.readthedocs.org/en/latest/toolchain/#step-1-compile-the-toolchain), [3](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html#packaging-with-python-for-android).

Comment: What issue do you see in particular?

Comment: It's the issue in packaging a Python 3.x app + required modules in the target platform's native packaging format, e.g. .MSI for Windows, .rpm for Linux, .APK for Android.